# Is there any practical difference between throw Exception('message') vs throw 'message' in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

Is there any practical difference between using:

```
throw Exception('message');
```

vs

```
throw 'message';
```

When I want to throw an error in flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`throw 'message'` throws a `String`.

Callers trying to catch it either would need to do:

```dart
try {
   throw 'message';
} on String catch (s) {
  ...
}
```

or would need to use a blanket, untyped `catch` clause ([which isn't recommended](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#only_throw_errors)).  Doing this would be very unusual and would not be behavior callers would expect.  There is an [`only_throw_errors` lint](https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules#only_throw_errors) to warn about this.

`throw Exception('message');` throws a constructed `Exception` object.  That's far more typical.

Comment: Just curious, the Linter rule doc u mentioned says it is back practice to throw an object that doesn't extend Error or Exception but it doesn't actually say why it is bad practice (apart from saying its a hack, which is also another way of saying bad practice). So just wondering what could go wrong if you use a blanket catch clause?

Comment: A bare `catch` clause is bad practice because it catches *everything*, including `Error`s, which you usually shouldn't catch either.  Catching `Error`s is bad because it hides what should be considered *logical* errors (such as `AssertionError`).  And throwing things that aren't `Error` or `Exception` is a bad practice because, as I said, callers won't expect it.